# R: If the last column element in the previous row is NA, make current row NA

Tags: r, function, if-statement, for-loop, na

I am writing a function that will take the largest elements in a vector V.Size and output into a matrix N by N+1. My problem is when V.Size is smaller than `N*(N+1)`. When this happens, the matrix starts by going to the top of the vector while I want it to output `NA`s.

For example:

```
# vector V.size is
V.size <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
# and N is
N <- 2

# then, the output matrix should be

   c1 c2 c3  
r1  6  5  4  
r2  3  2  1
```

And when `N*(N+1) > V.Size`, I want `V.Size` to fill it until `V.Size` runs out then return `NA`s instead of starting over.

My attempt to solve this problem is by by searching for when an element is larger than the previous and replacing it with an `NA`. My attempted solution returns the error:

```
Error in if (is.na(m)[(i - 1), (y + 1)]) { : argument is of length zero
```

Here's my code:

```
# Function Name: one
# Input: V.Size (a vector) and N
# Output: Matrix size N by N+1

# Code:
one <- function(x,y) {
  # sort the data, largest to smallest with N.A. last
  temp <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = TRUE)

  #creating the matrix
  m <- matrix(head(temp, (y*(y+1))), # only takes elements that fit in the matrix
    nrow = y,                     # number of rows = N
    ncol = (y+1),                 # number of columns = N+1
    byrow = TRUE)                 # filling it by row as instructed

  if (length(x) < (y*(y+1))) {    # if V.Size is smaller than the outputted matrix
    for (i in seq_len(y)) {       # for loop for columns 
      for (j in seq_len(y+1)) {   # for loop for rows
        if (m[i, j] > m[i,1]) {   # if the element is larger than the first in the row 
          m[i, j] = NA            # return NA
        }

# HERE IS WHERE THINGS FAIL:
        if (is.na(m)[(i-1), (y+1)]) { # if the last element in the previous row is NA 
         m[i, ] = NA                  # make current row NA
        }
      }
    }
  }

  # print the output
  m
}

# creating dummy data
V.Size <- c(1:10)
# choosing a dummy N
N = 5

one(V.Size, N)
```

I get the error: `Error in if (is.na(m)[(i - 1), (y + 1)]) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: I think you should elaborate your first line (as to what you are *actually* trying to do). That is, explain how you get from a `n` element vector to `n by n+1` matrix with an example. You may get better suggestions / answers.

Comment: Sir, I may have explained poorly, but my element vector is V.Size. I want to take V.Size and sort it, outputting it in a matrix form.

Comment: what's the logic to sort a vector into a matrix? Explain us your thought process. Show with an example how you get from a vector to a matrix. It's hard, if not impossible, to know what you think. Your question at the moment is "too localised", I'd say (finding bug(s) in your code).

Comment: Added an edit with what I am trying to accomplish. Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't know how it gets to `6:1`. What's the logic? What happens when N=3? Explain us how you get from 1:6 to 6:1 when N = 2. Not show us, but *explain*.

Comment: @Arun I'm sorry I formated wrong.

instead of 6:1 it should be what is above now, I cant format in this edit box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
V.size <- 1:6
N <- 3

matrix(sort(V.size, decreasing=TRUE)[1:(N*(N+1))], nrow=N, byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    5    4    3
[2,]    2    1   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: @Arun Perfect, Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for not only spending time answering but also figuring out the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in first time run of the loop. You shouldn't check for the condition when loop runs for first time. i.e. when **i-1 = -1 or i=1** then no check. There whould no previous member for the first time run!!!

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I create a matrix and search m[0,1] I get an output: integer(0). This led me to believe the first row would not be an issue.

Comment: What if at start i=0 and then i-1= -1.... Coz logically index start with 0 and 0-1 = -1 then it can create an error!